# jQuery save files via input or Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, cross-domain

I am working on a simple project based on HTML and jQuery (no server side). The HTML contains a form where user will insert an image, on submission a zip file will be created containing that image as well.

With the use of jsZip library I was able to add all the other files to the created zip file which are already presend. However the user can add image from anywhere (from some site or from a folder in his computer).

**TRY ONE**
I tried to use `input[type="file"]` so that user can browse the image which will later be saved in the image folder so that jsZip can easily access it.

**PROBLEM** 
I am unable to find any way to save the image in image folder without the involvement of server side language

---

**TRY TWO** I tried to use `input[type="text"]` for user to insert the image URL, then Ajax request to fetch the image to be added via jsZip.

**PROBLEM** It's generating an error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`

```
$.ajax({
        url: PageBGimage,
        type: "Post",
        contentType:'image/jpeg',
        mimeType: 'image/jpeg; charset=x-user-defined',
        success: function (json, data){
           // code to add image to jsZip
        }
    });
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/alikhan999/pen/MVvoOM

Comment: [This guide _uploading-files-ajax_](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax) may help you

Comment: friend this requires php and our project is simply a folder of html and js files in the user's machine. it will not even be hosted anywhere

Answer (score 0):

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked* is occurs when you've try to send an ajax request between two difference domain. but you can send a request to another domain if that domain allow you to.

Check whether `PageBGimage` is the same domain that hold your js file (file that send the request)

Comment: its a project that will be saved in user's machine. it will not be hosted anywhere.